# Who said 'You can't step into the same river once'?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, parmenides, zeno-of-elea

Heraclitus traditionally said 'You can't step into the same river twice'

Who, in response, said 'You can't step in the same river once'?

I would like to attribute it to Parmenides or one the Eleatics but is it someone more recent?

Comment: Not Parmenides for sure....

Comment: Wikipedia attributes this to one Cratylus,

Comment: And so does [Oxford Reference](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095646158):"*you cannot step into the same river once: the river is changing and gone even as a single event of stepping occurs.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is attributed by Aristotle in the Metaphysics to Cratylus, a follower of Heraclitus. Reference: Aristotle, Metaphysics, 4.5 1010a10-15.